# Running functions from a child directory

Tags: azure, azure-functions

So I have a deployment process that copies my web jobs to a folder structure like \app_data\jobs\triggered|continuous\jobname. I'm currently looking into keeping the existing folder structure for people who are self hosting and running jobs out of process not on azure, as well as wanting to be able to run azure functions. I was hoping just to put a function.json in the existing folder structure and have the functions picked up but I have multiple problems with this.

1. I have a run.bat which needs to copy dependencies from bin folder to jobs folder on run. I see docs on how to do this in java but nothing more on how configuration runs. Basically, I'd want to do a copy and then call my specific compiled function with parameters defined and not some Main() static method
2. I don't see how you'd tell the host.json file to look into a sub folder or even sub folders recursively.. There seems to be no docs on this other than possibly creating a new Job Host and specify it in code (which I do not what to do). I don't want any dependencies on azure libs.

So my next idea was that I could also just copy the jobs exe to the bin folder and then the problem with run.bat goes away (#1 above) and place all the functions in (\app_data\functions\jobname). But then I wonder how would I specify this sub folder that contains my functions..

Please help.

Source for my project can be found here if your curious (https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/tree/feature/azure-functions). I'm working on getting the following job working first (https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/blob/feature/azure-functions/src/Jobs/EventPost/Program.cs) Here is how my artifacts are created as part of the git deploy process (https://github.com/exceptionless/Exceptionless/blob/feature/azure-functions/build/Push-Artifacts.ps1#L41)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might help you is the [`ITypeLocator`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/663a508e8a851629c26a51e7de3af36629dfd120/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/ITypeLocator.cs), which gives you control over the types that are indexed. You can set your own `ITypeLocator` in `JobHostConfiguration`.

Another is [`WebHostSettings`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/661e8de8449865139d20fe019f789a65cfe5da33/src/WebJobs.Script.WebHost/App_Start/WebHostSettings.cs#L34), which lets you set `ScriptsPath` - where functions are discovered. This is not configurable at present while running in azure, I suggest you file an issue and put in a PR to change that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll log an issue. Is there any work arounds to the issues above. I have it deploying but I can't see if it's actually working. I do see it listed in scm (raw function output).

Comment: I ended up not being able to get this to work as I'd expect. I didn't want to implement any azure specific code like the ITypeLocator..